# Node.js: How to return current document from cursor in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, database-cursor

I'm trying to make a synchronous loop through MongoDB collection.

I've tried using `cursor.forEach()` in the following way:

```js
const mongodb = require('mongodb').MongoClient

mongodb.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', { useNewUrlParser: true }, (error, mongo) => {
  if (error) { return console.error(error) }

  let cursor = mongo.db('database_name').collection('collection_name').find()

  cursor.forEach(item => {
    console.log(item._id)
  })
});
```

But it doesn't work with synchronous operations.

So, I decided to use different approach using `cursor.hasNext()` & `cursor.next()`

It looks like this:

```js
const mongodb = require('mongodb').MongoClient

mongodb.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', { useNewUrlParser: true }, (error, mongo) => {
  if (error) { return console.error(error) }

  let cursor = mongo.db('database_name').collection('collection_name').find()

  getDocument(cursor)
});


const getDocument = (cursor) => {

  console.log(cursor._id))
  
  if (cursor.hasNext()) {
    getDocument(cursor.next())
  }
}
```

Apparently, it returns an error that there is no such thing as `cursor._id`. So, how do I get the body (content) of the current document from a cursor?

Comment: What do you mean by "synchronous loop"? Are you trying to print the result of the `find()`?

Comment: @kevinadi No. What I meant by saying synchronous loop, is function `getDocument` that takes the first document from collection, requests a web API and saves the content to a different collection. And only after that it takes the next document using `cursor.hasNext()` and `cursor.next()` and does the same thing. I cant use asynchronous loop cause the API has quotas and won't return any data if I make too many requests in some period of time